# Cisco IR829GW - Stuck booting into Rommon Mode 2

Tags: router

No confreg commands are recognized. No set variable commands are recognized.

At first I was able to factory reset the router and go into the initial configure boot menu options, then from there I loaded a new IOS image on to the flash, but after I deleted the old versions of the flash I am unable to factory reset and get back into the initial configure options.

Below is the set command output:

```
LICENSE_SERIAL_NUMBER=FTX2116Z09V
LICENSE_PRODUCT_ID=IR829GW-LTE-VZ-AK9
RET_2_RTS=20:13:16 UTC Wed Dec 14 2022
LICENSE_BOOT_LEVEL=
BOOT_IOS_SEQUENCE=0
RANDOM_NUM=87409147
BSI=0
RET_2_RCALTS=
LICENSE_SUITE=
BOOT_STRING_IOS=?
SB_CORE_VER=F01047X15.01ada48ab2015-04-03
SB_ML_VER=MA0061R06.0404022015
SB_BOOT_SRC=upgrade
BOOT_HV=bootstrap:ir800-hv.srp.SPA.2.6.27
```

Here is the output from dir command :

```
flash:
 pnp-tech-time
 pnp-tech-discovery-summary
 txw90r2-confg
 vlan.dat
 managed
 eem
 ir800-universalk9-bundle.SPA.159-3.M6a.bin
```

When attempting to boot system from flash I receive this error:

```
Booting image: system....
Error 15: File not found
```

Despite my dir command showing that the desired file is there.

I am awaiting a new rommon package to be sent to me, but without being able to boot rommon mode 2, I am not sure how I would apply the new package.

Answer (score 2):

This is the procedure for recovering a 'boot to rommon' issue on the IR800 series routers. It is much the same as most reasonably recent Cisco fixed design routers except that it seems to need 2 files. The hypervisor and the boot image.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/800-series-industrial-integrated-services-routers/200712-rommon-recovery-procedure-for-the-cisco.html

It covers the basic steps of getting the 2 files from a USB drive to the local flash storage of the router, and then booting into rommon mode 1 and then mode 2. You can also boot from a TFTP server using the rommon 'set' commands to configure an IP address and additional configuration options on the router to help it reach a TFTP server where you have the files it needs to boot.

Make sure you have the 2 required files or the router will not be able to boot completely. Once complete, set the boot configuration in the IOx configuration and copy it from running to startup configuration. Then reboot to test.

Comment: Great find on that article. I will give this a shot.